# console app that asks specified questions to each user

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a console app in C# that asks users to login first and then process to answering only specified questions for each user. What is the best way of doing it? I have four questions and I want only the first two questions to be asked to the first user and the other two for the second.

Here's my code below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String username;
    String password;
    int row;
    string[,] accnts = { { "jack", "111", "1" }, { "ibo", "121", "2" } };

    Console.Write("enter username >> ");
    username = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("enter password >> ");
    password = Console.ReadLine();

    for (row = 0; row < 3; row++)
    {
        if (username.Equals(accnts[row, 0]) && password.Equals(accnts[row, 1]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("welcome " + accnts[row, 0]);
        }

        else if (username.Equals(accnts[row + 1, 0]) && password.Equals(accnts[row + 1, 1]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("welcome " + accnts[row + 1, 0]);
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("invalid access");
            break;
        }

        string[,] question_id = { { "1", "1" }, { "1", "2" }, { "2", "3" }, { "2", "4" } };
        string[,] questions = { { "Türkiyenin baskenti neresidir?", "1" }, { "Baskomutan kim?", "2" }, { "2 kere 2?", "3" }, { "when did the world war 1 start?", "4" } };
        string[,] Answers = { { "a)ankara b)istanbul c)izmir", "1" }, { "a)ismet b)Atatürk c)Ali ", "2" }, { " a)1 b)2 c)4 ", "3" }, { " a)1912 b)1914 c)1915", "4" } };
        string[,] trueAnswers = { { "a", "1" }, { "b", "2" }, { "c", "3" }, { "c", "4" } };

        int result = 0;
        string answers = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < questions.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(questions[i, 0]);
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");

            for (int y = 0; y < Answers.GetLength(0); y++)
            {
                if (Answers[y, 1] == questions[i, 1])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Answers[y, 0]);
                    answers = Console.ReadLine();

                    for (int z = 0; z < trueAnswers.GetLength(0); z++)
                    {
                        if (trueAnswers[z, 1] == questions[i, 1])
                        {
                            if (trueAnswers[z, 0] == answers)
                                result = result + 10;
                            Console.WriteLine("total is  " + result);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (result < 20)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("failed");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("congrats");
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have *several* users, I suggest put them as well as qustions and answers into a *database*

Comment: yes you are right but since I am exploring 2d arrays,I only defined 2 different users and aimed to do it using arrays

Comment: Have you tried anything? Your question is too broad. The obvious answer is "figure out which user you're dealing with, and then only ask them the questions you want to ask them". But there are many different ways to go about doing that. If your code shows an attempt to do so which isn't working, you need to explain precisely what it is you're having trouble with. What does the code do, what do you want instead, and what _specifically_ can't you get to work? If your code is the "before" version and has no attempt to solve the problem, then you're not ready to ask a question yet.

Answer (score 2):

First let me tell you the totally wrong approach. This is the most dirty, quickest fix, that I can do:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String username;
        String password;
        int row;
        string[,] accnts = { { "jack", "111", "1" }, { "ibo", "121", "2" } };

        Console.Write("enter username >> ");
        username = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("enter password >> ");
        password = Console.ReadLine();

        for (row = 0; row < 3; row++)
        {
            if (username.Equals(accnts[row, 0]) && password.Equals(accnts[row, 1]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("welcome " + accnts[row, 0]);

            }
            else if (username.Equals(accnts[row, 0]) && password.Equals(accnts[row, 1]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("welcome " + accnts[row + 1, 0]);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("invalid access");
                // changed break to continue, because it was crashing
                continue;
            }


            string[,] question_id = { { "1", "1" }, { "1", "2" }, { "2", "3" }, { "2", "4" } };
            string[,] questions = { { "Türkiyenin baskenti neresidir?", "1" }, { "Baskomutan kim?", "2" }, { "2 kere 2?", "3" }, { "when did the world war 1 start?", "4" } };
            string[,] Answers = { { "a)ankara b)istanbul c)izmir", "1" }, { "a)ismet b)Atatürk c)Ali ", "2" }, { " a)1 b)2 c)4 ", "3" }, { " a)1912 b)1914 c)1915", "4" } };
            string[,] trueAnswers = { { "a", "1" }, { "b", "2" }, { "c", "3" }, { "c", "4" } };

            int result = 0;
            string answers = "";
            // here I've added a start and end thingy to offset the loop acording to logged user.
            int start = 0;
            int endModifier = 2;
            if (username == accnts[1,0])
            {
                start = 2;
                endModifier = 0;
            }
            for (int i = start; i < questions.GetLength(0) - endModifier; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(questions[i, 0]);
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");

                for (int y = 0; y < Answers.GetLength(0); y++)
                {
                    if (Answers[y, 1] == questions[i, 1])
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(Answers[y, 0]);

                        answers = Console.ReadLine();
                        for (int z = 0; z < trueAnswers.GetLength(0); z++)

                        {
                            if (trueAnswers[z, 1] == questions[i, 1])
                            {
                                if (trueAnswers[z, 0] == answers)
                                    result = result + 10;
                                Console.WriteLine("total is  " + result);
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            if (result < 20)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("failed");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("congrats");
            }

            return;
        }
    }
```

Of course you wanted the best approach to do it, I will use OOP (objected oriented programming)
First, I will create some helper classes to hold the data in:
An internal class for account...

```
    class Account
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public int Group { get; set; }
    }
```

An internal class for Question:

```
    class Question
    {
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public List<Answer> AnswersList { get; set; }
    }
```

And finnaly a Answer question to help us with the logic somewhat:

```
    class Answer
    {
        public string AnswerText { get; set; }
        public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }
        public string AcceptableLetter { get; set; }
    }
```

Filling these classes is easy, it is almost the same than your example, but with more polished names. List is your friend here, you can store all accounts in field but without those pesky indexes https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_8

```
List<Account> accountsList = new List<Account>();
accountsList.Add(new Account { UserName = "jack", Password = "111", Order = 1 });
accountsList.Add(new Account { UserName = "ibo", Password = "121", Order = 2 });
```

It is also good to split long code into small methods, so this method will check if the supplied username and password are correct and returns true or false.

```
    private static bool CheckUserPassword(List<Account> accountsList, string username, string password)
    {
        foreach (Account account in accountsList)
        {
            if (account.UserName == username)
            {
                if (account.Password == password)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("welcome " + account.UserName);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("invalid access");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

With accounts out of the way, I've also created a method to fill all answers in the quiz, where you can clearly see how to add more question if needed:

```
    private static List<Question> FillQuestions()
    {
        List<Question> questionList = new List<Question>();
        List<Answer> answerList = new List<Answer>();

        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "Ankara", IsCorrect = true, AcceptableLetter = "a" });
        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "Istambul", IsCorrect = false, AcceptableLetter = "b" });
        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "Izmir", IsCorrect = false, AcceptableLetter = "c" });
        questionList.Add(new Question { QuestionText = "Türkiyenin baskenti neresidir?", AnswersList = answerList });

        answerList = new List<Answer>();
        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "ismet", IsCorrect = false, AcceptableLetter = "a" });
        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "Atatürk", IsCorrect = true, AcceptableLetter = "b" });
        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "Ali", IsCorrect = false, AcceptableLetter = "c" });
        questionList.Add(new Question { QuestionText = "Baskomutan kim?", AnswersList = answerList });

        answerList = new List<Answer>();
        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "1", IsCorrect = false, AcceptableLetter = "a" });
        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "2", IsCorrect = false, AcceptableLetter = "b" });
        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "4", IsCorrect = true, AcceptableLetter = "c" });
        questionList.Add(new Question { QuestionText = "2 kere 2?", AnswersList = answerList });

        answerList = new List<Answer>();
        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "1912", IsCorrect = false, AcceptableLetter = "a" });
        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "1914", IsCorrect = true, AcceptableLetter = "b" });
        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "1915", IsCorrect = false, AcceptableLetter = "c" });
        questionList.Add(new Question { QuestionText = "When did the world war 1 start?", AnswersList = answerList });

        return questionList;
    }
```

And with this framework you could simply implement which questions are which, by adding property to Question class:

```
    class Question
    {
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public List<Answer> AnswersList { get; set; }
        // added property
        public int DesiredGroup { get; set; }
    }
```

and assigning which questions are for what group in FillQuestions() method:
     //code...
     questionList.Add(new Question { QuestionText = "When did the world war 1 start?", AnswersList = answerList, DesiredGroup = 2 });
     //code...

and then filtering each question in question loop:

```
 if (questions[i].DesiredGroup == accountsList.Find(x => x.UserName == username).Group)
 {
    continue;
 }
```

The if maybe little complicated, but the alternative is have CheckUserPassword method return account, or have it out parameter... this is quite lot information, so I leave it as it is.

Now the finished code looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Account> accountsList = new List<Account>();
        accountsList.Add(new Account { UserName = "jack", Password = "111", Group = 1 });
        accountsList.Add(new Account { UserName = "ibo", Password = "121", Group = 2 });

        Console.Write("enter username >> ");
        string username = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("enter password >> ");
        string password = Console.ReadLine();

        if (CheckUserPassword(accountsList, username, password))
        {
            List<Question> questions = FillQuestions();

            int result = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < questions.Count; i++)
            {
                if (questions[i].DesiredGroup == accountsList.Find(x => x.UserName == username).Group)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(questions[i].QuestionText);
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");

                WriteAnswers(questions[i].AnswersList);

                string answers = Console.ReadLine();
                for (int j = 0; j < questions[i].AnswersList.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (questions[i].AnswersList[j].AcceptableLetter == answers)
                    {
                        if (questions[i].AnswersList[j].IsCorrect)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(questions[i].AnswersList[j].AcceptableLetter + " is correct");
                            result += 10;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(questions[i].AnswersList[j].AcceptableLetter + " is incorrect");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (result < 15)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("failed");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("congrats");
            }
        }

        Console.Read();

    }

    private static void WriteAnswers(List<Answer> answersList)
    {
        char[] alphabetLetters = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
        for (int i = 0; i < answersList.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(alphabetLetters[i] + ") " + answersList[i].AnswerText);
        }
    }

    private static List<Question> FillQuestions()
    {
        List<Question> questionList = new List<Question>();
        List<Answer> answerList = new List<Answer>();

        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "Ankara", IsCorrect = true, AcceptableLetter = "a" });
        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "Istambul", IsCorrect = false, AcceptableLetter = "b" });
        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "Izmir", IsCorrect = false, AcceptableLetter = "c" });
        questionList.Add(new Question { QuestionText = "Türkiyenin baskenti neresidir?", AnswersList = answerList, DesiredGroup = 1 });

        answerList = new List<Answer>();
        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "ismet", IsCorrect = false, AcceptableLetter = "a" });
        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "Atatürk", IsCorrect = true, AcceptableLetter = "b" });
        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "Ali", IsCorrect = false, AcceptableLetter = "c" });
        questionList.Add(new Question { QuestionText = "Baskomutan kim?", AnswersList = answerList, DesiredGroup = 1 });

        answerList = new List<Answer>();
        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "1", IsCorrect = false, AcceptableLetter = "a" });
        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "2", IsCorrect = false, AcceptableLetter = "b" });
        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "4", IsCorrect = true, AcceptableLetter = "c" });
        questionList.Add(new Question { QuestionText = "2 kere 2?", AnswersList = answerList, DesiredGroup = 2 });

        answerList = new List<Answer>();
        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "1912", IsCorrect = false, AcceptableLetter = "a" });
        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "1914", IsCorrect = true, AcceptableLetter = "b" });
        answerList.Add(new Answer { AnswerText = "1915", IsCorrect = false, AcceptableLetter = "c" });
        questionList.Add(new Question { QuestionText = "When did the world war 1 start?", AnswersList = answerList, DesiredGroup = 2 });

        return questionList;
    }

    private static bool CheckUserPassword(List<Account> accountsList, string username, string password)
    {
        foreach (Account account in accountsList)
        {
            if (account.UserName == username)
            {
                if (account.Password == password)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("welcome " + account.UserName);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("invalid access");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    class Account
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public int Group { get; set; }
    }

    class Question
    {
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public List<Answer> AnswersList { get; set; }
        public int DesiredGroup { get; set; }
    }

    class Answer
    {
        public string AnswerText { get; set; }
        public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }
        public string AcceptableLetter { get; set; }
    }
```

There are always better approaches, but this is sufficient for now :)
Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Here's just a little piece. The longer answer from @OrilesElkar that tells you how to break this up into smaller classes is what you need.

Here's one more:

```
public class QuestionsByAccountProvider
{
    Question[] GetQuestionsForAccount(Account account)
    {
        // Put your code for providing questions here.
    }
}
```

Then from a different class you could call

```
var questionProvider = new QuestionsByAccountProvider();
var questions = questionProvider.GetQuestions(account);
```

This helps to keep different areas of your code separate so that when you look at your program you don't see the whole thing at once. That can be confusing even when it's your own code. At any given moment you're only looking at the part of the logic that you care about.

Also, as was pointed out, maybe later you'll want to put your questions in a database. If your questions are provided by a separate class then you can make your changes there and it's much easier. If it's all in one giant method then it gets much harder to change one part without breaking other stuff. This way your main method just knows that it's asking something to give it questions, and it doesn't care how that happens.

Or perhaps when you get this working you'll decide that you'd like to put it in a Windows Forms application or a web application. If your code is in separate classes you can add them to another type of app and they'll work the same. But if all of your work is in `Main` in your console app then it will be really hard to extract some pieces and reuse them.

It's helpful when one class can tell another what to do or get information from it without knowing anything about how that other class does its work. That way you can make changes to one class without affecting the other. You'll find that you spend more time with the "fun" part of writing code - figuring out how to make stuff happen - and less time trying to read it or debug it.

(A next step is [unit testing](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/02/19/unit-tests-hello-world.html), which is really awesome. I recommend learning about it early on. I wish I had.)